# Generating 21-vertex 4-regular plane graphs with 8 faces of degree 3 and 15 faces of degree 4

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, planar-graphs

Is there any way to generate all 4-regular plane graphs with 21 vertices, 8 faces of degree 3, and 15 faces of degree 4? If so, how many of these graphs are there and what are they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brinkmann and McKay's program `plantri` can generate *planar quadrangulations*, which are planar graphs with all faces of size 4.

If you generate these on 23 vertices and then filter to keep only those of minimum degree 3 and maximum degree 4 then you will have the dual graphs of what you want.

It took a couple of seconds and produced about 20 graphs (can’t remember exactly).

You may have to check carefully that assumptions about connectivity and the plane/planar distinction match what you want.

***Added Details***

I just did

```
plantri -q -g 23 | pickg -d3 -D4
```

The options on `plantri` are -q for "quadrangulations" and -g for "graph6 format".

Then pipe the output into `pickg` and ask for minimum degree 3 and maximum degree 4.

This produces 23 graphs in under a second.

Then find their planar duals - SageMath can do this and is convenient for visualising them anyway.

Here is the list that I obtained, one graph per line, where I have just concatenated the entries of the adjacency matrix to form one long 0/1-string.

```
010110010000000000000101011000000000000000010101100000000000000101000110000000000000110000001100000000000011000000110000000000001100000011000000000100100001001000000000000010010000110000000000011000000011000000000001100000001100000000000110000100100000000000001001000011000000000001100000001100000000000110000000110000000000011000010010000000000000100100011000000000000110000101000000000000011001001000000000000001110001000000000000000011110
010110000010000000000101001100000000000000010100011000000000000101000000101000000000100001000010100000000010010000000110000000010000010000011000000001000100000001100000001000000100000110000000100001001000010000100010000001000001000000100000110000000100000011000000000001010000001100000001000010000000110000010000001000000011000000010001000000001100000100100000000000010100000110000000000001000011001000000000000110001001000000000000001100110
011100100000000000000101110000000000000000110001010000000000000110010001000000000000010101000100000000000001010000011000000000100000011000100000000001000100001010000000000100100100001000000000010001010001000000000001000100000110000000001010000000011000000000100000011000100000000010000100001010000000001100100100000000000000010001010100000000000011000100001000000000001010000011000000000000100100011000000000000010001101000000000000000011110
010110010000000000000101011000000000000000010101100000000000000101000101000000000000110000000110000000000011000000011000000000001100000001100000000100000001100010000000000100010000101000000000010010000000110000000011000000000011000000001100000100001000000000101001000000100000000010000001100010000000001000010000110000000000100010010010000000000110000100001000000000011000000101000000000000101001001000000000000011100001000000000000000011110
010110000100000000000101001100000000000000010100011000000000000101000001010000000000100001000001100000000010010000000011000000010000010000001100000001000100000000011000001100000010000001000100000000011000000100000100001100000001000000010000100100000010000010000001010000001000001000000101000001000001100000010100000000000100000001010001000000010000000100110000000011010000000100000000000100000011010000000000001000010101000000000000110100010
010110000100000000000101011000000000000000010100110000000000000101000001100000000000110000000011000000000010000100001100000000001001000000011000000001000001000001100000000100010110000000000100100001010000000000000010001100000100000000011000000000110000000001000000010011000000000100000100001100000000110000000000110000000010011000000010000000000001100000011000000000000110000101000000000000011001001000000000000001110001000000000000000011110
010110000010000000000101001100000000000000010100011000000000000101000000101000000000100001000000110000000010010100000001000000010001010000001000000001000101000000100000001000010100000010000000100001001000010000100000000001100001000000100000110000000100000010000010000001010000010000000001000011000001100000010100000000000010000001010001000000001100000100100000000000010100000110000000000001000011001000000000000110001001000000000000010100110
010110000010000000000101001100000000000000010100011000000000000101000000110000000000100001000001100000000010010000000110000000010000010000011000000001000100000000110000001000000100000010100000100001010000001000100100000101000000000000010000010100001000000011000001000000010000001100000001000010000000100000010100001000000010000001010001000000011000000100100000000000101000000110000000001000000011001000000000000110001001000000000000001100110
010110000100000000000101011000000000000000010100110000000000000101000001100000000000110000000110000000000010000100011000000000001001000000110000000001000001000011000000000100010011000000000100110000010000000000000011001100000000000000001001000101000000000000100001000110000000000110000000011000000000010001000101000000000000000101000110000000000000110000011000000000000011000101000000000000000101011000000000000000110101000000000000000011110
010110000100000000000101001100000000000000010100011000000000000101000001010000000000100001000101000000000010010000000110000000010000010000011000000001000100000000110000001100000000000011000100010000010000000100000100000100000001100000010000000100000110000001000001010000010000001100000101000000000000100000010100010000000010000001010001000000011000000101000000000001010000010001000000000111000000001000000000001101000001000000000000000101110
011100010000000000000101011000000000000000110000101000000000000100010010100000000000010100000011000000000010000100001100000000001001000000011000000100100001000000100000001000010000001100000000100000010000110000000010000100000001100000011000000000000110000001000000010000011000000100000100010001000000101000000110000000000011100001000000000000000100011001000000000000010000010101000000000011000001010000000000001100000101000000000000110001010
011100010000000000000101011000000000000000110000110000000000000100010001100000000000010100000110000000000010000100011000000000001001000001100000000101000001000100000000000100010000011000000000110000000001100000000011000000000110000000001100000000011000000000110000010001000000000001000100001100000000001100000000110000000000110000010010000000000011000100001000000000001110000001000000000000011000011000000000000001100101000000000000000011110
010110001000000000000101011000000000000000010101100000000000000101000011000000000000110000000110000000000011000000011000000000001000010001100000000000100100000011000000100100000100001000000000010001010000100000000011000100000010000000001100000000011000000000100000010001100000000010000100000110000000011000000100010000000000100001010001000000000011000100001000000000001100000101000000000000110001010000000000000011000101000000000000000111010
011100010000000000000101011000000000000000110000101000000000000100010010100000000000010100000110000000000010000100011000000000001001000000110000000100100001000001000000001000010000011000000000110000000001100000000011000000000110000000001000000100011000000000100001000001100000000101000000000110000000011100000000010000000000110000000011000000000011000001001000000000001100010100000000000000110001001000000000000011100001000000000000000110110
011100010000000000000101011000000000000000110000101000000000000100010000110000000000010101000001000000000010010100000100000000001001000000011000000100000001100000100000001000010000001100000000100010000000011000000100000001000001100000010000010100000100000001000001010000100000000100000101000010000000101000010000001000000011000000010001000000000100000101001000000000110000010010000000000011100000010000000000000010001101000000000000001110010
011100010000000000000101011000000000000000110000101000000000000100010000110000000000010100000011000000000010000100001100000000001001001000010000000100000001100001000000001000110000000100000000100010000001010000000110000000000011000000011000000100001000000001000001010000100000000100000100100010000000010100000100001000000001000011000010000000000110000001001000000000011000010100000000000000100001011000000000000010100101000000000000001010110
011100100000000000000101011000000000000000110001010000000000000100010001100000000000010100000011000000000011000000001100000000100000011000010000000001000100000110000000000100100000001100000000100000010000110000000010000100000011000000011000000000001100000001010000000000110000000110000001000010000000001000010000011000000001100000010001000000000110000101000000000000011000010001000000000001100000011000000000000111000100000000000000001101100
010110000100000000000101001100000000000000010100011000000000000101000001010000000000100001000001100000000010010000000110000000010000010000011000000001000100000000110000001100000010000010000100000000011000001000000100001100000000100000010000100000001010000011000000010000010000001100000101000000000000100000010100010000000010000001010001000000011000000100100000000000101000000101000000000010000011001000000000001101000001000000000000000101110
011100100000000000000101110000000000000000110001010000000000000110000001100000000000010001000110000000000001010000011000000000100000011000100000000001000100001010000000000100100000101000000000110000000001100000000011000000000110000000001010000010010000000000101000010001000000000010001100000100000000001100000001010000000000110000000011000000000011000000101000000000000101000110000000000000010011001000000000000001101001000000000000000110110
010110000100000000000101001100000000000000010100011000000000000101000001010000000000100001000101000000000010010100000100000000010001010000010000000001000100000001100000001100000010000100000100010000010000010000000100001100000001000000010000000100010100000001000001010000100000000100000101000100000000010000010000011000000011000000001001000000000101000001010000000000010000110001000000000001110000010000000000000001010101000000000000001101010
010110001000000000000101001100000000000000010100110000000000000101000010100000000000100001000011000000000010010000000110000000011000000000011000000001100000000001100000100000000110000010000000100001000000101000000010001001000010000000010000010100000100000001000001010000010000001100000100000010000000110000000000011000000010100000001001000000001010000001100000000000100000110001000000000001000010011000000000000111000100000000000000001101100
010110000100000000000101011000000000000000010100110000000000000101000001100000000000110000000011000000000010000100001100000000001001000000011000000001000001000001100000000100010000000011000100100000010000001000000010000100000001100000011000000000000110000001000000010000011000000100000101000001000000110000010000001000000010000000010011000000001000000100110000000001110000000100000000000011000011000000000000001100110000000000000000111100000
011100010000000000000101011000000000000000110000101000000000000100010010100000000000010100000011000000000010000100001100000000001001000000011000000100100001000000100000001000010000001010000000100000010000101000000010000101000000100000011000010000000100000001000000010001100000000100000100000011000000101000000010001000000010100000010010000000001000001100001000000000100100000110000000000011100001000000000000000010101001000000000000011010010
```

Comment: 23 if the 3-connected ones are all you need.  Perhaps more if you allow lower connectivity or multiple edges.

Comment: Actually if such a graph exists then it shall be 4-edge-connected by a known result. I used plantri but it takes a couple of hours. Maybe I had some thing wrong while using plantri.  I just commanded plantri 23 -p -m4  -e46 -f4 .  So what is the correct command for the program? If possible, can you return me the output graphs here, either in -a or -T form. Thanks.

Comment: @XinZhang If the theory says that the graph is 4-edge-connected and simple (no multiple edges), or you don't want multiple edges, the quickest command is plantri -q -g -c2 23 which makes the duals.  Filter through pickg as Gordon says.  Or you can get the duals directly with "plantri -q -g -c2 -d 23 | pickg -T8". If you get serious about larger sizes, the optimal path is to add a filter inside plantri to remove the graphs with the wrong degrees. There are hooks for such purpose but they aren't so easy to use.