# Generating 12-vertex plane graphs with 2 faces of degree 3 and all other faces of degree 4

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

My question may be similar to [generating-21-vertex-4-regular-plane-graphs-with-8-faces-of-degree-3-and-15-face.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460587/generating-21-vertex-4-regular-plane-graphs-with-8-faces-of-degree-3-and-15-face.), but it has differences. The plane graphs I desire (without **needing regularity**) have only two 3-faces, while all other faces are 4-faces.

Brinkmann and McKay's program plantri can generate planar quadrangulations, which are planar graphs with all faces of size 4. The plane graphs I desire are very close to them, yet different.

Are there currently any tools available to obtain all these graphs?

P.S.  Constructing several examples is something I can do. For instance, I can start by a quadrangulation and then remove an edge.  In addition, there are other construction methods, such as in the graph below, where the two triangles do not share any common vertices.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions "max face = 4, 21 edges, 12 vertices" characterize them. So:

plantri -pf4e21 12  -- 125 outputs (these are the 3-connected ones)

plantri -pf4e21c2 12 -- 120857 outputs (these are the 2-connected ones)

There are none which are connected but not 2-connected.